# Win32 application windows eventually stop painting on Windows 7

Tags: winapi, user-interface, windows-7, interface, paint

I have a large, complex application written in C++ (no MFC or .NET).  The client that uses the software most aggressively will, within an hour or so of starting it, get to a state where all the windows stop painting.  We get reports that the application has "hung" because as far as they can tell nothing is happening.  In reality, the application is functioning, just not displaying anything.

I've tried a lot of different things to no avail.  I'm out of ideas...

Comment: How do you know the application is functioning if you don't see any controls on forms?

Comment: I run the task manager and end the task - at that point the application pops up to confirm closing / ask if you want to save / etc.  As if nothing was wrong.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You probably already have a hunch of what it is - you give it away in the first sentence

> ... large, complex application ...

It sounds like you have a GDI resource leak somewhere. To confirm this try looking in task manager at GDI objects for your process. At some point most GDI operations will fail for your application.

Make sure you are freeing all handles correctly. Note that different GDI objects require different methods of freeing the object. For example `GetDC` is freed by `ReleaseDC`, but `CreateDC` is freed by `DeleteDC`.

This is why RAII smart objects (like smart pointers) are recommended for resource management in C++ (where freeing is managed by the smart object to reduce the likelihood of leaks and errors).

Comment: I forgot about the GDI column on the task manager; thank you.  The app is apparently leaking a few GDI objects here and there.  With enough use, that may perhaps add up more quickly than I'd expect.  I'll plug those leaks and see what the client says (update to follow).

Comment: Forgot to come back and say so :(  This was the issue, and after plugging a few holes the problem is resolved.

Comment: this post save my job. 1 hour left before sending source code to our client, my win32 application crashes every 3 hours (the main form shows and hides 1000 times per hour, each time the background changes). This answer helped me finding the root cause that was GDI object. I fixed by deleting the brush object before assigning new value to brush variable.

Answer (score 5):

I'd bet that the application is leaking GDI objects, and when the GDI dedicated space for this process is exhausted, it can no longer paint itself.

You can check if this is the case by adding to the *Windows Task Manager* (or any other process manager such as *Process Monitor*) the column **GDI Objects** and see if this number grows unbounded with time.

Answer (score 0):

Your application may actually be suffering from an exception that is getting ignored. See [Microsoft KB article 976038](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976038).

Comment: Silently ignoring unhandled SEH exceptions from a callback does not exhibit the behavior the OP is describing. After all, their application is still fully functional, with the exception of updating the GUI. In the vast majority of cases this is caused by running out of GDI resources. You need to explain, why the implementation outlined in the KB article would cause the observed behavior.

Comment: @IInspectable Sorry, I can't remember that far back, but I guess my application had been getting exceptions in its paint callback.